# Ubuntu 14.04 HDMI UDev Script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell-script, udev

I have tried multiple variations to [this script](http://charlesmcruz.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/ubuntu-12-04-stoggle-hdmi-sound-toggleswitch/) but I cannot get it to work. The UDEV Rule fires the script and the script exectutes but simply does not change the audio profile.

If I run the script manually in terminal, it works but not when the UDEV Rule fires it... please help, thank you.

*Tl; Dr*

1. Udev fires script but does not switch audio profile and no notification is shown.
2. Manually running in terminal leads to the audio profile being switched with the notification correctly shown.

UPDATE: When adding a check on if the command worked, it reports that it failed. [Here](http://pastebin.com/2jDT2xRB) is a link to my whole script.